# Moving flask app to production from internal tool without rewriting it

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask web application build as an internal tool in our org.
now it is decided to move it to production ( on AWS ).
i can't find anything useful other than it says that Flask is not recommended for production.
Is there still some way to build setup of the flask app as the main web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask is well equipped to handle requests but yes it has it's own development environment which isn't recommended to use in production, you have to use proxy servers like uwsgi, gunicorn that replaces your development server.

Now you can also not handle request from uwsgi servers, you want a proper heavy duty reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache2 to do that work for you.[This might resemble the logical flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RyNY.png).

You can refer to below articles they explain such details clearly and with procedure.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

The message you are quoting about Flask not being ready for production only refers to the builtin development server.

You should use a WSGI server such as Gunicorn in combination with Flask.

Also, I usually put NGINX in front of them to handle SSL/TLS, or even Haproxy, depending in the expected load/availability.